# Javascript using Wix website builder

Tags: javascript, velo

While using some code to get an image url, I have ran into some issues, the code is saying `url.match is not a function.`

*Any help would be great!*

```
function youtube(url = $w('#input1')) {


        var regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

        var match = url.match(regExp);

        if (match && match[1].length === 11) {
            let urllink = match[1];
            let imagelink = "http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/" + urllink + "\/hqdefault.jpg\"";

            console.log(imagelink);
        } else {
            //Nothing
        }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you pass wrong type  url into  function

Comment: Any idea how I would fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **wix** documentation, `$w` function selects and returns elements from a page.

If you have an input on the page with id set to `input1` (you are trying to select it by calling `$w('#input1')`) than the variable `url` holds handle for the input, not the value of the input.

So try to get the value from it (like `url = url.value`, or just `url = $w('#input1').value`), and after than call `url.match(regExp);`.

Edit your function like this:

```
function youtube(url = $w('#input1')) {
    var regExp = /.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;

    url = url.value;
    var match = url.match(regExp);

    if (match && match[1].length === 11) {
        let urllink = match[1];
        let imagelink = "http:\/\/img.youtube.com\/vi\/" + urllink + "\/hqdefault.jpg\"";
        console.log(imagelink);
    } 
    else {
        //Nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this line of code before this event, it had the same outcome.

       `code`url = $w('#input1');
   
   var match = url.match(regExp); `code`

Comment: What line of code you've added and where? Did you call `url.value.match(regExp)`? Or?

Comment: Sorry, my error.  It is now working, when i added .value thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but better  will be  fix  default parametr like this :
function youtube(url = $w('#input1').value) {